# Give a hint that navigation in footer is expandable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, footer

In the new navigation the five categories listed under "Stack Exchange Network" slide open another drawer and sub-navigation to other SE sites. None of the other links in the navigation do that, they directly link to their targets.

[image: StackOverflow 2017 new footer nav]

If I hadn't seen the animated GIF in the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/27/new-stack-overflow-footer-pages-launch-today/?cb=1) I'd probably never have discovered this and never clicked on these links (because I know my way around the site via the network button in the top navbar).

There should be a hint there that the navigation is expandable and slides out. You could add a little arrow ">" to the list entries, or partially slide the sub-navigation into view on hover, or there might be much better ways to do it.

Comment: This! I saw the GIF and it still took 5 clicks to find what was expandable.

Comment: wait.... THAT'S EXPANDABLE?!

Comment: Not that I disagree, but chances are *very good* that the expandability feature only makes sense for one who uses the footer to navigate around like that.  Being told that it can expand may not add all that much value in my opinion.

Comment: I will never use that.

Comment: we've added small icon - waiting in repo for build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - We've added small icon next to each *category* so hopefully it's now more obvious.

Answer (score 9):

This has been pointed out to the product manager who'll be overseeing the next round of iterative work on the footer. Loads of A/B tests in the pipe these days; I'm not sure how close this one is to coming back around to the front of the queue again.

I also personally don't mind the "just stick a little arrow in line" approach. It looks a little janky when I just threw a `>` in there in five seconds, but I think it could be made to work nicely with a little attention from someone design-minded:

[image]

Before sinking a whole lot of thought into it, though, the first thing I'd like to know is: is this actually a regression? How many folks were actually using those links for navigation? IIRC, their main purpose is SEO for graduated Stack Exchange sites - giving some of SO's wealth of Google juice to the smaller communities. This admittedly quirky UI shouldn't have any effect on that aspect.

We can do research on this when it comes around again (since we have actual monthly product cycles now, like a grown-up product organization). Come to think of it, it's certainly possible that that research has already been done and I just missed it. I'll see if I can dig something up for y'all.

Comment: If it is just for SEO, why not hide it altogether? How often do humans click those links?

Answer (score 4):

*The following is merely a personal opinion which does not take into consideration any of the limitations that were present when re-designing the footer / entire site. The devs had their work cut out for them.*

---

**Here's a "before" screenshot:**
[image]

**What can be improved**:

- No indication the menu is expandable as the OP clearly pointed out.
- too much difference in height between the different lists.
- Culture / Recreation stands out (too long)
- Multi-line headings which lead to lists starting at different heights.

---

**Here's an "after" screenshot:**
[image]

**Changes:**

- Changed headings
- Moved *"contact us"* to the *Business* list
- Split Culture / Recreation into two separate items
- add indicators to show that "network" menu items are expandable - Got the idea from the OP and [hairboat's ♦ answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351363/8157693)

Comment: This should probably be a separate feature request, rather than an answer. Also it might make sense to split it into multiple requests since some people might agree with one of your requests, but not all. For instance, I like the idea of shortened 1 line headings, but I think culture/recreation are better together since when you separate them, the header becomes a whole line longer.

Comment: The problem with splitting Culture/Recreation into 2 categories is that it doesn't reflect SE's sites categorization on ["All Sites"](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation-oldest) page.